# how to add seach functionallity to php table with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, search

I have a very simple CSV file about books, I want to read data from the file to fill my PHP table
and search through the table using a javascript function. I'm able to get the PHP table to display how I want. but I can't seem to be able to link it with my javascript, and the table only shows up with filtered letters when you start typing if the input is empty the results don't show.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
    <?php
     
     $file_to_read = fopen('input .csv', 'r');
      
     if($file_to_read !== FALSE){
         
          
         echo "<table class=''myTable>\n";
         while(($data = fgetcsv($file_to_read, 100, ',')) !== FALSE){
             echo "<tr class='header'>";
             for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                 echo "<td class='tableitem'>".$data[$i]."</td>";
             }
             echo "<tr class='tablerow'>'\n";
         }
         echo "</table>\n";
      
         fclose($file_to_read);
     }
      
     ?>
    </body>
    <script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > 0) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
    
    
    </script>
    </html>
```

this is my output this is exactly what I want it to look like but it doesn't search or do anything
[!picture of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrWEc.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrWEc.png)

Comment: If the PHP part is working, it isn't relevant to the problem. You could exclude that part from your question, and instead show us a sample of the generated HTML.  That way we could actually run your code and see where the problem is.  See how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like you have some simple typos though - reading your code, I see 2 errors which will stop anything working.  1) The table class name is outside its quotes: `<table class=''myTable>`  2) Your `tr` variable is actually finding table cells: `tr = table.getElementsByTagName('td')`.  When you later try to find cells inside those cells you won't find anything.

Comment: _"if the input is empty the results don't show"_ - of course they don't, because `.indexOf("")` will always return 0. So you are setting every TR to display:none, when your `filter` value is an empty string. `if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > 0)` - why is this checking for _greater_ 0 to begin with? Do you not want to consider it a match, if the cell content _starts_ with the searched value?